# log4net RollingFileAppender won't advance index past .1

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my config... I've been at this for a bit and can't seem to get it outputing the way I want.
My output files are as follows after two runs

- log-file_2014.02.20.xml
- log-file_2014.02.20.1.xml

Which is what I would expect, but when I run it a third time.  I would expect to see log-file_2014.02.20.2.xml however...  the actively logging file replaces the file with no index "log-file_2014.02.20.xml", and the file that had no index gets moved to one with the .1 index and the one that had the .1 index is deleted!  So my indexes never go past .1 for any given date.  Did ya follow that... Any help would be grateful!

```
      <!-- Logging Configuration Details-->
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="fileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="Logs/log-file_" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd'.xml'"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="BloombergSwapData.AdvancedLayoutXml"/>
      <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout"/>-->
      <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>-->

    </appender>

  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="fileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <param name="File" value="Logs/log-file_" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd'.xml'"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="BloombergSwapData.AdvancedLayoutXml"/>
  <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout"/>-->
  <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>-->

</appender>
```

use this configration... Hope it helps... :)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood.  I want it to create a new file each time not append to the existing one.  The new file should get created and the index increased...  ie... logfile.xml,logfile.1.xml,logfile.2.xml, etc...  but it's never making it passed .1.xml